# Contact.php send emails but without the text message inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, contact-form

I implemented the following contact form on my website (from a template), and I can send and receive an email message successfully, but the message part (the users text) is NOT received in my Inbox. 
I receive the Name and From Email, but not the content of the message.

[screenshot from the website form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d9ec.png)

Can someone help finding and fixing the issue? It is the php, the jQuery or the html wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="contact.php" class="contact_form" id="form" method="post">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
                    <span class="input input_name">
                        <input class="input__field" type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
                        <label class="input__label" for="name">
                        <span class="input__label_content">Name</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input input_website">
                        <input class="input__field" type="url" name="website" id="website" />
                        <label class="input__label" for="website">
                        <span class="input__label_content">Website</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input input_mail">
                        <input class="input__field" type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
                        <label class="input__label" for="email">
                        <span class="input__label_content">email</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
                    <span class="textarea">
                        <textarea class="textarea_field" name="textarea" id="textarea" rows="4" placeholder="type your text here . . . ."></textarea>
                    </span>
                    <span class="submit">
                        <button type="submit" class="rms-btn submit_btn" id="submit">submit request <span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**contact.php:**

```
<?php
/*
* Ajax form submit
*/

# request sent using HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){
        if (isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email'])  AND isset($_POST['textarea'])) {
                $to = 'info@antarescodestudio.com'; /* Add your contact email address here */

                $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $message = filter_var($_POST['textarea'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $sent = email($to, $email, $name, $message);
                if ($sent) {
                        echo 'Message sent!';
                } else {
                        echo 'Message couldn\'t sent!';
                }
        }
        else {
                echo 'All Fields are required';
        }
        return;
}

/**
 * email function
 *
 * @return bool | void
 **/
function email($to, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message){
        $header = array();
        //$header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        $header[] = "From: {$from_name} < {$from_mail}>";
        $header[] = "Message: {$message}";
        /* Set message content type HTML*/
        /*$header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";*/
        /*$header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";*/
        if( mail($to, $message, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true;
}

?>
```

**contact.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var form = jQuery('#form'); // contact form
    var submit = jQuery('#submit'); // submit button
    var alert = jQuery('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
        // sending ajax request through jQuery
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'contact.php', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('Email Sent <span> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> </span>'); // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

with

```
$message = filter_var($_POST['textarea'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

**Edit:** Also this line is questionable:

```
$subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

There are no fields with a name `subject`.

Comment: I have updated the contact.php form, but I still have the same issue anyway. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your text area has the name 'textarea', while in your php file you are processing `$_POST['message']`. Change the name of the textarea to 'message' or `$_POST['message']` to `$_POST['textarea']`

Comment: I have updated the contact.php form, but I still have the same issue anyway. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Please, check the mail function docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php `$subject` must be set before `$message`

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the textarea is names `textarea` on your form, but you are referencing a POST variable called `message`.